# Traducir を SO 社内インフラに移行します

Tags: 討議, 翻訳, 他言語サイトでの提案, traducir.win

2018 年に [Stack Overflow スペイン語版 で Traducir を使い始めてから](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3378/11272) 長い月日が経ちました。当初は、ユーザーからのコントリビューションを受け入れるだけでなく、直面している問題や実装のアイデアについて話し合うことができるオープンソースとして開発されました。

[Traducir](https://traducir.win/) の最も素晴らしい点は、Stack Overflow 多言語版が直面していた問題を、私たち多言語版コミュニティ自身が構築したツールを使用して解決できたことです。

2018 年は Traducir を機能させるために多くの時間を費やしましたが、それ以降で私が行った重要なメンテナンス作業は React を使用しないようにフロントエンドを書き直すことだけでした（維持するのに多くの作業が必要であることが判明したため）。それ以外は SO 多言語版サイトで使用し始めた時期を含め（現在すべての SO 多言語版コミュニティが翻訳を提案、入力するために使用していますが）特に問題なく機能しています。

次のグラフをご覧ください。メンテナンスがほとんど必要なく機能するものを構築できたことを誇りに思います：

[image: GitHub graph showing the contributions to the Traducir project]

Traducir の開始以来、Traducir は私の個人開発用インフラストラクチャの環境で実行されてきました。以前は、サイト公開前にコミュニティマネージャーが翻訳を手動でレビューしていたためそれほど心配はなかったのですが、しかしそのプロセスが自動化されて以来、自分でホスティングすることに少し不安を感じていました。（私はソフトウェア開発にフォーカスを置いていて、サイト信頼性エンジニアではありません。）

Stack Overflow 社を最初に離職したとき、traducir.win ドメインの所有権を SO 社に譲渡しましたが、アプリケーションは私の個人開発用インフラで実行し続けました。SO 社を再び（今月末で）離職することになったので、この責任も肩から下ろしたいと思います。

このため現在、 Traducir を SO の社内インフラに移行する計画を立てています。つまり今後、Traducir は SO 社によって保護、稼働、メンテナンスされる環境に置かれます。

この移行の一環として、以下を計画しています：

1. [現在の Traducir リポジトリ](https://github.com/g3rv4/Traducir) を Stack Overflow のプライベート GitHub 組織にフォークします
2. 現在のリポジトリをアーカイブします（コードを公開して参照できるようにしますが、パブリックリポジトリが維持されていないことをクリアにするため）
3. アプリケーション自体を SO 社のインフラに移動します

これは、コミュニティが問題を解決するためのプルリクエストを送信できなくなることを意味します。しかし、コードのコントリビューション履歴を調べたところ、スタッフ以外による重要なコントリビューションが最後に行われたのは 2019 年であることがわかりました（それも元スタッフによるものでした）。この移行作業によって、Traducir を使用してコミュニティが翻訳を提案、入力することへの影響は特に（数分間のダウンタイムを除いて）ありませんが、状況を皆さんにお知らせしたいと思い、ここに共有しています。

というわけでお知らせです！Traducir を SO 社に正式に引き渡すことができてほっとしています。:) コメントや質問がある場合は、本投稿に記入してください。また、Traducir で問題が発生した場合（または改善を提案したい場合）は、いつでも Meta に投稿してください。（必要に応じてサイトモデレーターは [エスカレーションを行いスタッフの注意を促す](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348642/238921) ことができます。）

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします！

Comment: Thank you @g3rv4 for maintaining an awesome tool for international sites!

Comment: <3 hope it continues providing value for a while... or even better, hope our translation story improves and it's no longer needed!